# How to flip random bits in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-express

For testing purposes I want to update a table by setting bits in colums to a random value.

```
update [Planned] 
set [IsPlannable] = 1 * rand(cast(cast(newid() as binary(8)) as int))
WHERE [ComputerID] > 100
```

It does seem to work as it should *but not the way I want it*. I guess the problem is the result will most of the time be higher than 1.

How can I **flip random bits** to **random values**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `1 *` is still yielding a fractional number & given that `cast(0.1 as bit)` will yeild 1 as will `cast(0.9 as bit)` the updates are all set to 1.

You could;

```
update Planned set IsPlannable = case when rand(cast(newid() as binary(8))) < 0.5 then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: would that if/else have any severe performance impact? Not that this is the case right now, but for later use of this pattern?

Comment: I would not have thought so, the expensive rand(cast(newid().. would only be evaluated once, plus you can change it to introduce a bias.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how many bit fields you have to use, you can generate all of the possible settings using something like this:

```
with test as (
    select 0 as myId, cast(0 as bit) col1, cast(0 as bit) col2, cast(0 as bit) col3
    union all
    select myId + 1, 
        case when myId & 1 = 1 then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end,
        case when myId & 2 = 2 then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end,
        case when myId & 4 = 4 then cast(1 as bit) else cast(0 as bit) end
        from test
        where myId<100
)
select distinct col1, col2, col3 from test
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
cast(round(rand(), 0) as bit)
```

Comment: In what way? It works fine for me on SQL Server 2008 R2, which version are you using?

Comment: This flips the bit to a single value for all rows the same :)